# Are promises in the psalms for today?

Tags: psalms

Can we still today claim promises in the psalms for today? Or did they ended when the NT was written?

For example psalm 145 14 "The lord upholds all who fall and lifts up all who are bowed down"
And verse 19 "He will fulfil the desire of them that fear him: he also will hear their cry, and will save them."

Comment: **All the promises of God** are 'Yea !' and 'Amen !' - in Christ Jesus. 2 Corinthians 1:20. Up-voted +1.

Comment: God's words and promises cannot change. The writers of the NT themselves used or recalled the scriptures. Nothing can be expired. It is applicable to all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. God's word is eternal (Luke 21:33) - living and active. It accomplishes all it commands (Isaiah 55:11). The promises of the psalms are as true and applicable today as they were when written. Jesus words in the NT are in alignment with and addition to the old testament. You will find many that say almost the same thing. Eg: Blessed are those who mourn for they shall be comforted.

He created a new covenant which became available to man but this does not negate the truth of the old testament scriptures.

As Jesus stated Mat 13:52

> So Jesus said to them, “That is why every student of the Scriptures
> who has become a disciple of the kingdom of heaven is like a home
> owner. He brings out both new and old things from his treasure chest.

Both old testament and new contains treasure

Isaiah 55:11

> So is my word that goes out from my mouth: It will not return to me
> empty, but will accomplish what I desire and achieve the purpose for
> which I sent it

Luke 21:33

> Heaven and earth will pass away, but my words will never pass away.

Answer (score 2):

Of course for today also, but after the New Testament complete divine revelation in the Lord Jesus Christ the same verses should be read in the Light of the Lord, who is the Light of the world (John 8:12).

For example, let us discuss the passages you give: Psalm 145 14: "The lord upholds all who fall and lifts up all who are bowed down" And verse 19 "He will fulfill the desire of them that fear him: he also will hear their cry, and will save them."

Of course the Lord upheld in Old Testament times and He upholds in our New Testament times, but in Old Testament times the Lord would help a man falling to adultery, that is to say, to have sex with another woman than his wife, in the New Testament times the same Lord helps a man not only with such a fall, but even from a fall to look lustfully at a woman (Matthew 5:27-28); thus the semantics of "fall" changed and got new nuances and dimensions in the Light of the New Testament.
And He did hear those who cried to Him for salvation in Old Testament times and would save them from visible enemies, even by miracles, by separating the Red Sea; but in New Testament times He hears those who cry to Him for salvation, which means not only delivering them from visible perils, but also for helping them defeat the power of sin, demons and give them citizenship of Heavenly Kingdom through grace of His Son. Thus, the same words, but the semantics of "salvation" changed and enriched quite drastically.

Answer (score 1):

The promises made in the Psalms are for the **children of the promise**.  Note the following:

- 2 Cor 1:20 - For all the promises of God are “Yes” in Christ. And so through Him, our “Amen” is spoken to the glory of God.
- Rom 9:6, 8 - For not all who are descended from Israel are Israel. ... So it is not the children of the flesh who are God’s children, but it is the **children of the promise** who are regarded as offspring.
- Gal 3:29 - And if you belong to Christ, then you are Abraham’s seed and heirs according to the promise.

It is for this reason, that the NT so often quotes from the Psalms and applies them to Christians.  Christians for centuries have derived much hope and assurance from the promises found in the Psalms.

**More Detail**

As the above verses declare, many of the promises are fulfilled in Christ and we receive these promises via our great mediator of the new covenant, Jesus Christ (Heb 9:15, 12;24). For example -

- Ps 23 declares, "The LORD is my Shepherd" and Jesus said, "I am **the** good Shepherd" (John 10:11).  Thus, all the protection and succor promised in Ps 23 we obtain through Christ.